# Are there clearly defined ways to tie necktie knots?

Tags: clothing

[image]I wore neckties for about three or four years after getting a job, after which I stopped wearing them since the company I work for actually didn't require them.

But after looking at several websites or YouTube videos discussing the art(or science) of wearing neckties, I found that there were several types of knots widely used, but that the specifics of wearing each type of knot was not well-defined. Ideally, you would want your final result to contain the following characteristics :

1. The thick end of the tie should rest on your belt
2. The thin end of the tie should be sufficiently tucked into its nest behind the thick end
3. The knot at your neck should not be too tight nor too loose.
4. The size of the knot should be adequate.

In my case, I prefer a half-Windsor knot, since it leaves room for both #1 and #2 to be satisfied, and not sacrifice the length of either side for the sake of a larger knot size. It does lend itself to slightly smaller knots, which, when combined with a slightly loose fit, creates a knot that doesn't fill in in between the collars. But I'd rather salvage my health than nitpick myself on small details like that.

However, even here, I made some custom "rules" so as to have consistent results :

1. With the necktie on the rear end facing forth, put the lowest guideline in the middle of your shirt*
2. Have the thin end rest in the middle of the lowest guideline
3. Have the thick and thin end maintain a 30~40 degree angle*
4. Tie the [Simple Knot](https://www.pinterest.co.kr/pin/443815738276845080/).

- There are a total of two visible guidelines when the thick end is put near the center of your body. There are two other guidelines towards the thinner end, which face the opposite direction to the visible guidelines when the thick end is put in the center of your body, but I'm guessing that those guidelines don't have much of a purpose? Correct me if I'm wrong here.
- Here, my "theory" is that the greater the angle between the two ends, the shorter the thicker end has to be, if you were to adhere to rule #1.

My question is, the following

1. Is there anything wrong with any of my four rules?
2. Does everyone make custom rules like this?

Comment: Hi Guest, Welcome to Lifehacks. We hope you enjoy your stay and sharing what knowledge and hacks you have. Let me invite you to [Tour] and [Help] to get to know more about how the site works and to get the maximum from it. As it happens, your questions don't seem to need a hack as defined by our site. Thus, you may find your question down voted or even closed. You don't have enough points to comment; but, you can edit your question to better fit within our qualifications for a good and fitting question.

Comment: Honestly, I’m afraid you got few things wrong. The reason why your kind of „rules“ won’t work is because of both the wearers and their preferred knot. Speaking from experience in helping multiple men tie their ties for formal occasions. Taller people have to adjust the height difference between thin and thick end differently than shorter wearers, and that’s for the same knot. If you switch knots, you need again a different start position and if you are a perfectionist, even the material/pliability will require slight adjustments. But it’s good for *you* to have a guideline what works for you.

Comment: Pro tip: the type of knot should match your collar type, some shirts are designed for narrower ones, others have an extra-wide angle that should be filled out with a wider knot.

Answer (score 3):

Since this site isn't about the usual ways to do something, my **hack** is to buy a ready-made tie. The one I used has a different design: no neck band – it just clips over the top of the shirt.

[image]
<sup>*Image from Amazon*</sup>

People have been using ready-made **bow ties** for a long time. Anyone who can actually tie one is thought to be a bit of a genius.

Comment: LOL, my grandpa wore the clip-on type. I (female) learned to tie a necktie when I was in my teens and it’s been a handy skill now and then. Thanks for the trip down memory lane!

Comment: @Stephie thanks I can tie both kinds, although I need several attempts to get the bow tie right. Just because your grandpa used a ready-made one does not make them obsolete (not a Dad joke). They are available in the shops even today.